# Unable to extract model object from web api OK() response

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I have a model class

```
 public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public DateTime Dateofjoin { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int IsActive { get; set; }
        public int row_number { get; set; }

    }
```

another model class using 'Employee' model class  as list

```
  public class EmployeeList
    {
        public IList<Employee> Emp_List { get; set; }
        public int Return_Param { get; set; }
    }
```

I am calling an api method to get employee records along with a return parameter.

```
  public IHttpActionResult Get_Employee()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            var displaydata = db.Get_Employee();
            return Ok(displaydata);
        }
```

here displaydata returns object of 'EmployeeList' model class and got Emp_List and Return_Param successfully. 
I have another controller from where make call to api method and extracts the response from OK method returned.

```
     public ActionResult Get_Employee()
        {
            EmployeeList empobj = new EmployeeList();
            try
            {

                empobj.Emp_List = new List<Employee>();
                HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
                hc.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);
                var consumeapi = hc.GetAsync("EmployeeApi");
                consumeapi.Wait();
                var readdata = consumeapi.Result;
                if (readdata.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    empobj.Emp_List = readdata.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Employee>>().Result;
                    empobj.Return_Param = Convert.ToInt32(readdata.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                }             
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout) { }
                else throw;
            }
            return View("EmployeeList",empobj);
        }
```

But I am not able to extract the model object instead getting exception which states cannot deserialize to json. How could I get empobj.Emp_List and empobj.Return_Param if(readdata.IsSuccessStatusCode)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var consumeapi = hc.GetAsync("EmployeeApi");` calls your `Get_Employee()` api method, right?
I think your code needs to be

```
if (readdata.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    empobj = readdata.Content.ReadAsAsync<EmployeeList>().Result;
}
```